# Assistance with Doctrine ODM query

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have the following query which is providing undesired results.

```
 $query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Discussion')
        ->field('id')->equals($discussionId)
        ->field('discussion_id')->equals($discussionId);
```

What I am trying to do is to find any documents where id = $discussionId OR discussion_id =$discussionId.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have the methods `add()` and `addOr` of query builder:

```
$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Discussion');
->add($query->field('id')->equals($discussionId))
->addOr($query->field('discussion_id')->equals($discussionId));
```

Also you can replace the `add` and <strike>`addOr`</strike> methods by `where` and `orWhere`

Comment: the `addOr` is deprecated now :s. But the `add` stills. For addicional reference you can see the [Query Buider Docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html)